# MS-Excel Graph/Picture

Tags: excel

I currently have a table as shown which users must input a from and to number, chose a key (picture) and enter which columns it will cover. My question is how would i make it so that there is a drop down box so that the keys may be selected, when the key is chosen the user can then input a column number e.g. from 0-6 which will then produce the picture to the graph from the length and columns that have been inputted. my explanation may not do justice but i have provided a picture which is very simple to understand the concept. please let me know of any solutions for this problem. Thankyou.

Process:
Step one - input chainage e.g 0-50

step two - pick the key (picture) e.g 1

step three - chose column number range e.g. 0-3

This will then insert the picture with a length (chainage) of 50 (starting at 0) and will have a width from 0-3.

[image]

Comment: I think you're looking for two solutions to tie together to get what you want: 
 [dependent drop-down lists](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) and an [image drop-down list](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/20ce9414-fcad-4545-90e3-042dda7c11a2/how-do-i-create-a-excel-drop-down-list-with-a-list-of-imagespictures). See if those links help.

Comment: Thankyou, they seem like very helpful links!

Comment: how would i make the selected drop down key to fit the graph cells then?